# Is the construction of $\mathbb{R}$ by Cauchy sequences due to Cauchy? For that matter, are Cauchy sequences due to Cauchy?

Tags: math-history

A little bit of cursory searching around on Wikipedia reveals only that Cauchy sequences are *named* after Cauchy—but I already knew that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a reasonably detailed sketch of the history [here.](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/HistTopics/Real_numbers_2.html) The first Cauchy sequence type of construction was given by Méray, though there had been a partial anticipation by Bolzano. Much closer is the construction of Heine, and of Cantor. The constructions of the last three appeared in the period 1869-1872. Cauchy has no direct connection with the constructions, he worked with Cauchy sequences of reals.